# Sending EMAIL from c# code over office365 returns: TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported by your organization

Tags: c#

I am trying to send an email from code:

```
string recipients = "info@asd.com";

            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
            {
                Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                Port = 587,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false, // This require to be before setting Credentials property
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("support@asd.net", "asd"), // you must give a full email address for authentication 
                TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com", // Set to avoid MustIssueStartTlsFirst exception
                EnableSsl = true // Set to avoid secure connection exception
            })
            {

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
                {
                    From = new MailAddress("support@asd.net"), // sender must be a full email address
                    Subject = "hi",
                    IsBodyHtml = true,
                    Body = "<h1>Hello World</h1>",
                    BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                    SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,

                };
                var toAddresses = recipients.Split(',');
                foreach (var to in toAddresses)
                {
                    message.To.Add(to.Trim());
                }

                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
```

But i am getting an exception which reads:

e   {System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 550 5.7.67 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported by your organization. Please contact your administrator. [AS8PR04CA0080.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com]   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.CheckStatus (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient+SmtpResponse…}

Did I do anything wrong here?

Best

Comment: [MS (and well, everyone else) has disabled TLS 1 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/transport-layer-security-1x-disablement). Whoever you calling is potentially using an out of date protocol and MS have blocked it. Contact whoever your calling and get them to enable TLS2 support

Comment: Add: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` after you configure your `SMTP` client.