# Enabling TLS1.2 support in smtp.office365.com (.Net Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We're testing an iPhone app that sends an email to a specific email address. The developer is using `Xamarin.Forms`. He says it's a *class library project for Xamarin.iOS*.

When our iPhone app sends an email, we get the following error. The email is sent because I log on to `sender@MyCompany.com` and I notice that the emails are in the *Sent* folder:

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 421 X.XX.XX TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls. [DXXP273CA0011.AREP273.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.CheckStatus`

While researching, I found this question: [Sending EMAIL from c# code over office365 returns: TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported by your organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70879162/sending-email-from-c-sharp-code-over-office365-returns-tls-1-0-and-1-1-are-not)

I implemented the line of code in the question, plus the following snippet. I continue receiving the same message.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |         SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

How can I enable TLS1.2 support?

He added the following line, but I continue receiving the error:
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

I'm still waiting to see if it made a difference.

For what it's worth, I'm also including the code:

```
void test()
{
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@MyCompany.com");
        mail.To.Add("receiver@yahoo.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test Subject";
        mail.Body = "Lorem Ipsum";

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@MyCompany.com", "MyPassword");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you wait until you test the pending fix to see if it works?  If not, knowing what project this code is in (Forms or iOS) and what framework version that project is using would be very helpful.

Comment: You're right. I just assumed that since that comments didn't get any upvotes, it meant that it didn't work.

Comment: try this: ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;  // | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

Comment: Neither of them worked. Still getting `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 421 X.X.XX TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls. [DXXP273CA0011.AREP273.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.CheckStatus`

Comment: can you please response to the questions I asked above?

Comment: The developer is using Xamarin.Forms. He says it's a class library project for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: That doesn't answer either question.  Regardless, you might try using MailKit instead of System.Net.Mail

Comment: We're using Visual Studio for Mac v.8.10.24 (build 4).

Comment: He tried MailKit, and he says that it worked in Debug mode _but not working with production ( unable to generate production ipa)_.

Comment: Again, that doesn't answer the question.  I'm trying to get at which Framework version you're using, which would determine which version of SmtpClient you're using.  And if MailKit worked but you couldn't generate an IPA with it, then perhaps you should focus on **that** problem instead of just giving up on it?  MailKit is actually built by a member of the Xamarin team.

Comment: I didn't know the developer was using MailKit. After I mentioned it to him, that's when he mentioned that he tried MailKit.

Comment: We're using .Net Core 2.0.